# Simplify writing if/else collection of Django queries

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have code in a Django `views.py` that looks like:

```
if query_type == 'list':

    if column == 'person':
        person_qs = Person.objects.filter(name__in = query_items_set)

    elif column == 'grandparent':
        person_qs = Person.objects.filter(grandparent__name__in = query_items_set)

    elif column == 'child':
        person_qs = Person.objects.filter(child__name__in = query_items_set)

elif query_type == 'regex':

    if column == 'person':
        person_qs = Person.objects.filter(name__regex = regex_query)

    elif column == 'grandparent':
        person_qs = Person.objects.filter(grandparent__name__regex = regex_query)

    elif column == 'child':
        person_qs = Person.objects.filter(child__name__regex = regex_query)
```

When it comes to writing views, is there a more accepted/concise way of avoiding repitition, while still maintaining readability and extensibility? Or do `views.py` files tend to look like this? Or are dispatch tables more common?

Comment: After doing some more research I feel like a dispatch table is a possible answer here, and I'll be writing an answer for myself.

Comment: Not really sure what your use-case is, the `django-filter` package is quite popular for handling complex or repetitive filtering like this

Comment: @IainShelvington thanks. Looking into that.

Comment: what I want to point out here is table structure looks little disturbing to me.
what is ```Person``` is doing in ```Person``` table. if this tables mentions the relation between table. a better way would be something like a different table with person1, person2 and relation as fields.
take it as a suggestions :)

Comment: @shivankgtm ha! sorry -- I cooked up this example from my real table. That was a typo from doing search/replace. Let me know if it still disturbs you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone who suggested `django-filter`.

`> pip install django-filter`

`settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django_filters',
]
```

`views.py`

```
class PersonFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = {'name': ['in', 'regex'], 
                  'child__name': ['in', 'regex'], 
                  'grandparent__name': ['in', 'regex']}

        ...

        person_qs = PersonFilter(request.GET, queryset = Person.objects.all().qs
```

Answer (score 0):

For cases like this [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) (Django REST Framework) is a common and very useful solution. [Here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/) are the docs about filtering.

An example.

View:

```py
from myapp.models import Person
from myapp.serializers import PersonSerializer
from rest_framework import generics

class PersonList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
    filter_backends = [
        SearchFilter
    ]
    search_fields = [
        'name', 'grandparent__name', 'child__name',  # For substring search
        '$name', '$grandparent__name', '$child__name'  # For regex search
    ]
```

And you will also need a `Serializer`:

```py
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'
```

That's all.